# How to multiple subquery with avg and sum also count?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So i have this logic which i'm having a hard time to implement it into my query..
I wanted to get an average value of the data but not including the ACCOUNT_TYPE 'EXAMPLE_1'
This is my code for now since i still think how to figure it out
(1)

```
SELECT 
ACCOUNT_TYPE
,ROUND(avg(MARKET_PRICE),4) AS MARKET_PRICE--i intended to change it with number (2)
,sum(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY--i intended to change it with number (2)
FROM TABLE_A
```

and this is what i plan to do with it(2)

```
CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_TYPE <> 'EXAMPLE_1'
THEN ROUND(MARKET_PRICE/(SUBQUERY_B-SUBQUERY_A),4) AS MARKET_PRICE
ELSE NULL

CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_TYPE <> 'EXAMPLE_1'
THEN (SUBQUERY_C) AS QUANTITY
ELSE NULL
```

and this is my subquery that i needed to implement into my query

```
--THIS IS SUBQUERY_A
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
TABLE A WHERE ACCOUNT_TYPE <> 'EXAMPLE_1'

--THIS IS SUBQUERY_B
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
TABLE A WHERE ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'EXAMPLE_1'

--THIS IS SUBQUERY_C
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM TABLE_A WHERE ACCOUNT_TYPE <> 'EXAMPLE_1'
```

I hope my explanation is pretty clear since i don't know how to say it better in English :(
So ,first , i wanted to get an average from that market price. So let's Say market price has 4 data(s), 2 has account type example_1, the other 2 has account type example_3 and example_4.
So there are 4 data(s) but i wanted to exclude the example_1 , so there are only 2 data(s) to do my average. So (market_price example_3+market_price example_4)/((count_data account type <>example_1 )-(count_data account type = example_1)).

The same goes with my sum, i wanted to sum all data but excluding the example_1 data.
The problem is i needed to select all account type that's why i can't use where condition in the bottom after FROM TABLE_A

Maybe someone can help ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Sum(case when ACCOUNT_Type <> 'EXAMPLE_1' then market_price end)
/ sum (case when ACCOUNT_Type <> 'EXAMPLE_1' then 1 end) as avg_market_price
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will compile, however, I think you are attempting do bring aggregations up from a subquery and mix them in with detailed data as outputs.

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_TYPE <> 'EXAMPLE_1' THEN ROUND(MARKET_PRICE/(SUBQUERY_B - SUBQUERY_A),4) ELSE NULL END AS MARKET_PRICE,
    CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_TYPE <> 'EXAMPLE_1' THEN SUBQUERY_C AS QUANTITY ELSE NULL
FROM
    TABLE_A A
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            ACCOUNT_Type,
            SUBQUERY_A = SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_Type <> 'EXAMPLE_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0),
            SUBQUERY_B = SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_Type = 'EXAMPLE_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0),
            SUBQUERY_C = SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_Type = 'EXAMPLE_1' THEN QUANTITY ELSE NULL END) 
        TABLE A
        GROUP BY
            ACCOUNT_Type
    )AS Detail ON Detail.ACCOUNT_Type = A.ACCOUNT_Type
```